# GDAL GDALWriteBlock has a problem with number of blocks you need to correct for

Tags: image, gdal

This is solution to a problem with writing images with GDAL. I hope others can benefit from my struggling. I took me over one month to understand that the problem was inside the GDAL write routine and not in my own software.

Use of blockread/write is not well explained in GDAL so I wanted to present a solution that works so others can use it. Blockwrite is much faster that the normal write routine and should be used if speed is important.

My program worked very well for a long time writing perfect images from my software until one day I decreased the resolution so that the number of cols and rows became small. then the result went crazy and I did not understand why.

My whole code is further down. Here is the problem that I needed to solve

```
switch (MapImage->edatatype)
{
case GDT_Byte:
{
    for (iYBlock = 0; iYBlock < nYBlocks; iYBlock++)
    {
        for (iXBlock = 0; iXBlock < nXBlocks; iXBlock++)
        {
            for (int bandnum = 0; bandnum < MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands; bandnum++)
            {
                p_poBand[bandnum] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(bandnum + 1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
                GDALWriteBlock(p_poBand[bandnum], iXBlock, iYBlock, &MapImage->uchar_tmatrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock* nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
break;
```

My original code was:

```
&MapImage->uchar_tmatrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock* static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
```

The correct code should be:

```
&MapImage->uchar_tmatrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock* nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
```

I needed to increase that address of the source data according to nYBlockSize. For all high res data nYBlockSize was set by GDAL to 1 and caused no problem. With low res data the nYBlockSize can be 2, 3 or higher. This is something inside GDAL you have no control over.

```
void WriteRasterFile(clImage* MapImage, int outfiletype)
```

{

```
GDALAllRegister();
char** papszMetadata;
GDALDataset* poDstDS;
int bRasterCounts = MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands;
GDALRasterBand** p_poBand = (GDALRasterBand**)CPLMalloc(sizeof(GDALRasterBand*) * bRasterCounts);

GDALDriver* poDriver;
const char* pszFormat = "GTiff";

//////////// check the driver /////////////////////////

switch (outfiletype)
{
case 31:
    pszFormat = "GTiff";
    break;
case 15:
    pszFormat = "GTiff";
    break;
case 44:
    pszFormat = "PCIDSK";
    break;
default:
    pszFormat = "GTiff";
    break;
}

poDriver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName(pszFormat);
if (poDriver == NULL)
{
    printf(" poDriver == NULL\n");
    exit(1);
}

papszMetadata = poDriver->GetMetadata();
if (CSLFetchBoolean(papszMetadata, GDAL_DCAP_CREATE, FALSE)) {};
//printf("Driver %s supports Create() method.\n", pszFormat);
if (CSLFetchBoolean(papszMetadata, GDAL_DCAP_CREATECOPY, FALSE)) {};
//printf("Driver %s supports CreateCopy() method.\n", pszFormat);//printf(".");

////////////// create() dataset ///////////////////////////
    char** papszOptions = NULL;
    //papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions, "TILED", "YES");
    //papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions, "COMPRESS", "PACKBITS");

int n = MapImage->outFileName.length();
// declaring character array 
const char* pszName = MapImage->outFileName.c_str();
GDALDataType eDataType = MapImage->edatatype;       //Normalt unsigned short, men her står vi friere til å velge data type
poDstDS = poDriver->Create(pszName, static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize), static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->ySize), bRasterCounts,
    eDataType, papszOptions);
//}
if (poDstDS == NULL) {
    printf("poDstDS == NULL \n");
    CPLGetLastErrorMsg();
}

//vi bruker blockwrite!
char a[6];
sprintf_s(a, "%d", static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize));
papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions, "BLOCKXSIZE", a);
papszOptions = CSLSetNameValue(papszOptions, "BLOCKYSIZE", "1");        //tiled image ,one line from each raster
//image first line and 

////////////// write the options to the file //////////////////
double mEast = MapImage->navdata.UTMMinEast;                //(newminEast + Easting);       //newminEast er beregnet fra senterpunkt på bildet
double mNorth = MapImage->navdata.UTMMaxNorth;              //newmaxNorth + Northing;               //newmaxNorth er beregnet fra senterpunkt på bildet

//negative resolution north
if (MapImage->navdata.ResolutionNorth > 0.0000001) MapImage->navdata.ResolutionNorth = -1 * MapImage->navdata.ResolutionNorth;      
if (MapImage->navdata.ResolutionNorth == 0.0) MapImage->navdata.ResolutionNorth = -1;

double adfGeoTransform[6] = { mEast, MapImage->navdata.ResolutionEast, 0, mNorth, 0, MapImage->navdata.ResolutionNorth };       //0, means North up
OGRSpatialReference oSRS;
char* pszSRS_WKT = NULL;

if (poDstDS != NULL) { poDstDS->SetGeoTransform(adfGeoTransform); }
else {
    printf("\n kan ikke poDstDS->SetGeoTransform( adfGeoTransform )\n");
    exit(-1);
}

oSRS.SetUTM(atoi(MapImage->navdata.UTMSone), TRUE);     //TRUE == North
oSRS.SetWellKnownGeogCS("WGS84");
oSRS.exportToWkt(&pszSRS_WKT);
poDstDS->SetProjection(pszSRS_WKT);
CPLFree(pszSRS_WKT);

/////////////////// find the correct value and transfer ///////////

int        nXBlocks, nYBlocks, nXBlockSize, nYBlockSize;
int        iXBlock, iYBlock;


p_poBand[0] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
p_poBand[0]->GetBlockSize(&nXBlockSize, &nYBlockSize);

nXBlocks = (p_poBand[0]->GetXSize() + nXBlockSize - 1) / nXBlockSize;
nYBlocks = (p_poBand[0]->GetYSize() + nYBlockSize - 1) / nYBlockSize;

/************* test of data type ****************/
switch (MapImage->edatatype)
{
case GDT_Byte:
{
    for (iYBlock = 0; iYBlock < nYBlocks; iYBlock++)
    {
        for (iXBlock = 0; iXBlock < nXBlocks; iXBlock++)
        {
            for (int bandnum = 0; bandnum < MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands; bandnum++)
            {
                p_poBand[bandnum] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(bandnum + 1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
                GDALWriteBlock(p_poBand[bandnum], iXBlock, iYBlock, &MapImage->uchar_tmatrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock* nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
break;

case GDT_UInt16:
    for (iYBlock = 0; iYBlock < nYBlocks; iYBlock++)
    {
        for (iXBlock = 0; iXBlock < nXBlocks; iXBlock++)
        {

            {
                for (int bandnum = 0; bandnum < MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands; bandnum++) {
                    p_poBand[bandnum] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(bandnum + 1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
                    GDALWriteBlock(p_poBand[bandnum], iXBlock, iYBlock, &MapImage->uint16_tmatrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock * nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;

case  GDT_Int16:
    for (iYBlock = 0; iYBlock < nYBlocks; iYBlock++)
    {
        for (iXBlock = 0; iXBlock < nXBlocks; iXBlock++)
        {

            {
                for (int bandnum = 0; bandnum < MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands; bandnum++) {
                    p_poBand[bandnum] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(bandnum + 1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
                    GDALWriteBlock(p_poBand[bandnum], iXBlock, iYBlock, &MapImage->int16_tmatrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock * nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;

case  GDT_UInt32:
    for (iYBlock = 0; iYBlock < nYBlocks; iYBlock++)
    {
        for (iXBlock = 0; iXBlock < nXBlocks; iXBlock++)
        {

            {
                for (int bandnum = 0; bandnum < MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands; bandnum++) {
                    p_poBand[bandnum] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(bandnum + 1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
                    GDALWriteBlock(p_poBand[bandnum], iXBlock, iYBlock, &MapImage->uint32_tmatrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock * nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;

case  GDT_Int32:
    for (iYBlock = 0; iYBlock < nYBlocks; iYBlock++)
    {
        for (iXBlock = 0; iXBlock < nXBlocks; iXBlock++)
        {

            {
                for (int bandnum = 0; bandnum < MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands; bandnum++) {
                    p_poBand[bandnum] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(bandnum + 1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
                    GDALWriteBlock(p_poBand[bandnum], iXBlock, iYBlock, &MapImage->int32_tmatrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock * nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;


case GDT_Float32:
    for (iYBlock = 0; iYBlock < nYBlocks; iYBlock++)
    {
        for (iXBlock = 0; iXBlock < nXBlocks; iXBlock++)
        {

            {
                for (int bandnum = 0; bandnum < MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands; bandnum++) {
                    p_poBand[bandnum] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(bandnum + 1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
                    GDALWriteBlock(p_poBand[bandnum], iXBlock, iYBlock, &MapImage->float32matrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock * nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;

case GDT_Float64:
    for (iYBlock = 0; iYBlock < nYBlocks; iYBlock++)
    {
        for (iXBlock = 0; iXBlock < nXBlocks; iXBlock++)
        {

            {
                for (int bandnum = 0; bandnum < MapImage->pHeading->numOfBands; bandnum++) {
                    p_poBand[bandnum] = poDstDS->GetRasterBand(bandnum + 1);  //bands go from 1 to bRasterCounts
                    GDALWriteBlock(p_poBand[bandnum], iXBlock, iYBlock, &MapImage->float64matrix->bands[bandnum][iYBlock * nYBlockSize * static_cast<int>(MapImage->pHeading->xSize)]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}

//////////// Clean up //////////////////////////////

/* Once we're done, close properly the dataset */
GDALFlushCache(poDstDS);
GDALClose((GDALDatasetH)poDstDS);
```

}

My complete write function uses block write since it is very much faster. I think C++ version is a little different. If you have any suggestion to make this function faster, please let me know.